# How do I put comments on each line in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I used to be a C# developer so this commenting style was very easy in C#. This is driving me crazy but how do you do this in VB.NET without getting a syntax error?:

```
Private ReadOnly Property AcceptableDataFormat(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) As Boolean
    Get
        Return e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) _          'this is a file that a user might manipulate
                OrElse e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor")   'this is a typical Outlook attachment
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: For your information, this has been driving VB programmers crazy for years. :-( That said, in your example I would highly recommend putting the comment *before* the complete statement. Having comments at the end of the line makes them a bit unreadable. But the problem of course persists, since continued lines currently cannot be interrupted by comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.  VB.Net doesn't allow comments to appear in the middle of statements which span multiple lines (including both explicit and implicit line continuations).  The comments must go above the statement or on it's final line.

The exception to this rule is statement lambdas.  It is fine for comments to appear within a statement lambda even though it's technically one statement.

Comment: Even though this feature has been requested ages ago. :-( Question to you as someone with a bit of insider information: Is the parser really that hard to rewrite to accommodate this change?

Comment: @KonradRudolph honestly the cost is the IDE code. Think of the impact this could have on the pretty lister and formatting and then factor in the age of the IDE code base.  That's the cost.  Changing the actual parser to ignore the comments is small potatoes.

Comment: OK, the parser in the IDE then. I still don’t see it. “factor in the age of the ID code base” – touché. But hasn’t this been (or is being?) rewritten from scratch with Roslyn?

Comment: @KonradRudolph the IDE and compiler use the same parser (Roslyn and pre-Roslyn) so the cost is shared.  The cost of actually parsing and consuming the code is small IIRC.  The difficulty is making it work with a collection of IDE features and in IDE code base that for 10+ years didn't expect it to be there.  It was seriously considered and investigated in the 2010 release but we ended up choosing features like implicit line continuation and statement lambdas over it.  If there had been more time I think we would've done it (none of us slept much during the 2010 release as it was).

Comment: @KonradRudolph as for what Rosyln's behavior will be.  I can't comment on that because I don't actually work on that team anymore :(

Comment: @KonradRudolph There are [semi-official rumours](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/677378/feature-request-line-comments-for-multi-line-statements-in-vb-net) that it will be implemented in Rosyln. See comment from Lucian in the link "We do aim to get this particular feature into the Roslyn parser. At the moment, though, it's still a long way off, and we're not making any commitments or announcements yet.".

Answer (score 3):

Remove that comment from the line continuation and it should be fine.  Comments cannot be used with the line continuation. The line continuation has to be the last character on the line so your comment cannot appear after it.

Here is a similar question: [Why must VB.Net line continuation character be the last one on line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748174/why-must-vb-net-line-continuation-character-be-the-last-one-on-line)

So like this:

```
 Private ReadOnly Property AcceptableDataFormat(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) As Boolean
        Get
            'Return a file that a user has dragged from the file system 
            'or a typical Outlook attachment
            Return e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) OrElse   
                   e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor")         

        End Get
    End Property
```

This is a limitation that has been bothering VB developers for a long time.

Comment: You cannot have the comment in the middle of the line. The line continuation is still there(if you remove the character it is implied) so you need to move the comment to before or after the block of code.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I want to happen :-) But thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is now possible in Visual Studio 2017

```
Public Function foobarbaz(ByVal foo As Integer,   '' qux
                          ByVal bar As String,    '' quux
                          ByVal baz As DateTime)  '' garply

  Return foo.ToString &         '' Concatenate foo
         bar &                  '' with bar
         baz.ToString           '' and baz

End Function
```