# Commenting ASP.Net code when using the '_' character

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, comments

This might be a really easy one but I couldn't seem to find an answer anywhere

I'm trying to comment my code as follows

```
Session("test") = "JAMIE" _ 
'TEST INFO
& "TEST" _
'ADDRESS INFO
& "ADDRESS = TEST"
```

With the code above i'm getting the error

> Syntax error

But when I remove the comments like so

```
Session("test") = "JAMIE" _ 
& "TEST" _
& "ADDRESS = TEST"
```

It works fine so my guess is that I cannot comment my code between the `_` character.

Is there some way I can get around this as I'd like to comment my code ideally

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I put comments on each line in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537010/how-do-i-put-comments-on-each-line-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_` character is the line continuation. It means that the next line is interpreted as if it was on the same line.

So, putting a comment in the middle of the line is a syntax error.

---

Since you want a solution:

- Either put a comment before the continued line or after it

---

As Tim Schmelter points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570043/284240), you can construct the value that will go into the `Session` object *before* you put it into the `Session` object - you can do that is separate statements and comment those to your hearts content.

Comment: Yes... but my question is - is there a way around it?

Comment: But the whole point in the question is asking if its possible? I would like to add comments in there to help other developers out

Comment: @JamieTaylor - And the answer is just that. No, it is not possible.

Comment: If I put the comment before the line continues it comments out the whole line?

Comment: @JamieTaylor - You mean before the `_`? I mean before the line containing it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8545/discussion-between-jamie-taylor-and-oded)

Comment: very inconvenient. :) I have a 9 line string (sql query) that is being built using & _ and I need to change a line. I would like to comment out the original line for historical reasons. So I understand where this question is coming from. I have to refactor the code just so I can comment. :(

Answer (score 3):

As Oded has mentioned, The `_` character  continues the line so you cannot comment between.

You could write:

```
Dim value = "JAMIE"
'TEST INFO
value &= "TEST" 
'ADDRESS INFO
value &= "ADDRESS = TEST"
Session("test") = value
```

Because that may create separate strings internally just to comment them, you could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) here. You could show us what you're really tring to do, so that we can suggest a different approach(if you need to comment each "line" of a single variable, you should consider to redesign the way you assign the value to the variable).

Comment: +1 For giving the OP excellent advice on their code, rather than just answering their original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Text.StringBuilder str = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

str.Append("JAMIE");
str.Append("TEST");//TEST INFO
str.Append("ADDRESS");//ADDRESS INFO
```

---

```
public string Test
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToString(Session["TEST"]);
        }
        set
        {
            Session["Test"] = value;
        }
    }
```

---

```
 Test = st.ToString();
```